# How to make a responsive and scrollable main panel for a SPA application?

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, single-page-application

I'm working on a SPA application which is going to have a responsive design too.

The plan is to have a fixed height header (30px), then a filled content, and a fixed height footer (20px). Just like a TableLayoutPanel (Absolute:30,Percent:100%,Absoulte:20) in winforms.

The content area filled the whole available space due to the size of the viewport and wont cause an overflow to show browser's scroll bar. Instead, the content area have an inner scroll bar. All of the contents are going to load in this area, so in case of need it will show the scroll bar.

[image]

As I searched and communicated with SO friends I came by this solution:

```
<div class="shell">

<header class="shell-header">Header Info</header>

<div class="main-row">
    <div class="main-scroll">
        <section class="main"
            data-bind="router: { transition: 'entrance', cacheViews: true }">
        </section>
    </div>
</div>

<footer class="shell-footer">Footer Info</footer>
```

And this is the styles:

```
.shell {
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.shell-header {
    width: 100%;
    display: table-row;
    height: 30px;
}

.shell-footer {
    width: 100%;
    display: table-row;
    height: 20px;
}

.main-row {
    display: table-row;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.main-scroll {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 1100px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.main {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    max-width: 1100px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
}
```

This solution works fine on Firefox and Chrome and after any resizing everything is OK.
But in IE 10 the `div class="main-scroll"` doesn't fill it's parent and it's height is `0px` in the layout.

**Question 1:** Why is that so?

**Question 2:** What is the workaround for IE10?

Comment: try adding `-ms-box-sizing: border-box;` to your `.main-scroll`

Comment: @AdrianEnriquez no, it doesn't take any effect. thie `box-sizing` seems to be supported since IE 8 and the `-ms` version of it seems to be for older versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your HTML and BODY tag set to height:100%? Because percentages are based on the parent element, not the viewport. This being said, I would recommend using the following code.

The HTML (inner HTML body tag):

```
<header>
     Fixed header here
</header>
<section>
    <p>Text here</p>
</section>
<footer>Fixed footer</footer>
```

The CSS:

```
html {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
body {
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
header {
    height:30px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    background-color:black;
}
section {
    padding: 30px 20px; /* first number needs to be higher then height header/footer */ 
    box-sizing:border-box;
    height:100%;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
footer {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    bottom:0;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    background-color:black;
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't test it on Internet Explorer since I'm a Mac user. Here is a link with the JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ykt98/2/ 
Also keep in mind, HTML5 tags needs to be 'faked' in some (IE) browsers by Javascript.

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: You fiddle works fine. But as this question is too old, I can not test it on my real project. I tested your fiddle with edge which is OK.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question in a google search, so thought I would add another answer that uses more modern techniques.

```css
*, ::before, ::after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
section {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
header, footer {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<header>
     Fixed header here
</header>
<section>
    <p>Text here</p>
</section>
<footer>Fixed footer</footer>
```